# Prompt Text for javaFX ChoiceBox

Tags: javafx-8

I want to add "Please Select" as the **promptText** for javaFX ChoiceBox component.Can any one please help me.

(Note:- This is not the default selected value. It is the value that display before get select any thing)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use `ComboBox` instead. It is similar to `ChoiceBox` but has a promptText property.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.getItems().addAll("Item 1", "Item 2");
        combo.setPromptText("Please Select");
        vbox.getChildren().add(combo);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```